# Filtering using multiple regex pattern specifications in R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have a filtering problem where I'm trying to select observations based on the presence of strings with any one of 4 different patterns:

1. A string of 10 consecutive digits (ex. 1250126681)
2. A string of 13 consecutive digits (ex. 9781626724266)
3. A string beginning with "id" and followed by 9 consecutive digits (ex. id975448501)
4. A string (length=10) of a combination of capitalized letters and digits (ex. B004TLHNOC)

This is a sample dataset:

```
FromName<-c("PubA","PubB","PubC","PubB","PubC","PubB")
PostName<-c("https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1250126681/ref=as_li_tl","https://www.amazon.com/dp/B004TLHNOC/ref=sr_1_1","https://us.macmillan.com/books/9781626724266",
            "https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/six-of-crows/id975448501","http://www.anrdoezrs.net/links/7992675/type/dlg/sid/MAChhjan32018eman/https://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/something-to-howl-about-christine-warren/1127202692","https://www.amazon.com/Beach-House-Cookbook-Mary-Andrews-ebook/dp/B01M2UZS7F/")
df<-cbind(FromName,PostName)
```

The output should look like this:

[image]

I think the regexes for the first 2 patterns are: ^[0-9]{10}$ and ^[0-9]{13}$, and I think [a-z]{2}\d{9} should work for selecting observations with the third pattern, but I'm stuck on pattern #4. I'm also unsure of how to combine multiple regex patterns into a dplyr filter function.

Comment: What about `^(?:\d{10}(?:\d{3})?|id\d{9}|[A-Z\d]{10})$`? You need to escape backslashes in r.

Comment: @ctwheels thank you. I assume the {3} is supposed to be {13}, representing a 13 digit string? I don't understand your comment about escaping backslashes in R. Is this factored into the pattern you just gave me, or is there additional logic I'd need to add?

Comment: In R a regex is a string, but `\ ` is a special escape character even inside strings. So to have `\d` in your regex you need `\\d` in the string representing the regex.

Comment: @user3614783 exactly what CalumYou mentioned, but the `(?:\d{3})?` is optional, so it's just tacking it onto the end of the `\d{10}` instead of specifying them separately as `\d{10}|\d{13}`. You could use either method. Without the `$` anchor, using `\d{10}|\d{13}` would only catch the first ten digits (unless you reversed the order of the options).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regexes should work:

```
[0-9]{10}
[0-9]{13}
id[0-9]{9}
[A-Z0-9]{10}
```

You should not need `^` and `$`, as you're trying to match something inside the string. `^abc$` would match `abc`, but not `xabcx`.

The second pattern will return a subset of the fourth. Any string of 10 digits is also a string of 10 digits or capital letters. So you only need three patterns to match those four categories. Unless you want to somehow differentiate between 10-character strings of ONLY integers from those with integers and characters, but it doesn't seem like that's the case.

You can use `|` to check multiple patterns. However, this will return the first match. E.g. `str_extract('abcdef','abc|def')` returns only `abc`. If you know that each URL will have no more than 1 match of any category, just do that.

I like using `str_extract` from `stringr`:

```
ProductID = str_extract(PostName, 'id[0-9]{9}|[0-9]{13}|[A-Z0-9]{10}')
```

Comment: I hadn't considered that one pattern was a subset of another and that I could use three patterns to match to four categories. Thanks also for pointing out that your approach only returns the first match. Not an issue for this dataset, but good to be aware.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data above is a matrix, we can cbind the results as below:

You can use `basename`:

```
cbind(df[,1],basename(sub("ref.*","",df[,2])))
     [,1]   [,2]           
[1,] "PubA" "1250126681"   
[2,] "PubB" "B004TLHNOC"   
[3,] "PubC" "9781626724266"
[4,] "PubB" "id975448501"  
[5,] "PubC" "1127202692"   
[6,] "PubB" "B01M2UZS7F"
```

or you can do:

```
cbind(df[,1],sub(".*\\/(\\w+)\\/(?>ref.*)|.*\\/(\\w+)\\S{1,2}$","\\1\\2",df[,2],perl = T))
     [,1]   [,2]          
[1,] "PubA" "1250126681"  
[2,] "PubB" "B004TLHNOC"  
[3,] "PubC" "978162672426"
[4,] "PubB" "id97544850"  
[5,] "PubC" "112720269"   
[6,] "PubB" "B01M2UZS7F"
```